# Understanding `iwlist keys` output

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I'm trying to understand the output of `iwscan list` for a Wireless adapter I own.

The manual page says:

```
   keys/enc[ryption]
          List the encryption key sizes supported  and  list
          all the encryption keys set in the device.
```

And the output I receive is :

```
wlan0  2 key sizes : 40, 104bits
      4 keys available :
            [1]: off
            [2]: off
            [3]: off
            [4]: off
      Current Transmit Key: [1]
```

What key do the two key sizes refer to ?

What are the 4 unoccupied keys ?

What is the transmit key ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at configuration for [WEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy), the original and completely obsolete Wi-Fi encryption standard. It had a very simple system (no keying handshake, no KDF), just a raw static hexadecimal key for the RC4 encryption algorithm.

WEP devices could be programmed with four keys – one is selected as the "active" transmit (encryption) key, but all four work as receive (decryption) keys. So there's nothing more to it – "current transmit key" tells you which key is used when transmitting.

I *think* this feature might have been used for key rotation (if you program both the 'current' and 'next' keys, devices no longer need to switch at precisely the same time), and/or isolation between devices (some devices using key 1, others key 2, etc).

---

Note 1: The `iwconfig` and `iwlist` tools are built on WEXT, which modern Linux Wi-Fi drivers no longer use. Although the current nl80211/cfg80211 framework still provides emulated WEXT support, all the new features go into the nl80211-based `iw` tool instead. (There are some exceptions, e.g. a few Realtek drivers still use WEXT.)

Note 2: **None** of these tools deal with WPA at all – you won't be able to set your WPA passphrase through 'iwconfig' nor through 'iw'. Both WPA1 and WPA2 (RSN) use dynamic keying which is performed by `wpa_supplicant` or `iwd` daemons.